# How to trigger loader function after form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a basic journaling app based using some inspiration from Journalisticapp.com. I'm using this as a way to learn/practice React and React Router.

The `Entries` component should contain a list of journal entries that are pulled with a loader function on the `/journal` index route. Each entry is added via React Router form element, then submitted to `/entry/add` with an action function.

After submitting the form I want the journal entries to update, but it requires a full page reload. How can I get only the `Entries` component to reload after submitting the form without having to reload the page?

**Routes.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import localforage from 'localforage';

import RootLayout from './layouts/RootLayout'
import JournalLayout from './layouts/JournalLayout';
import Entries from './components/Entries';

const journalDB = localforage.createInstance({
    driver: localforage.INDEXEDDB,
    storeName: 'journalDB',
})

const EntryList = await journalDB.getItem('entries') || []

const addEntry = (entry = { id, content }) => {
    journalDB.setItem('entries', [...EntryList, entry]).then((entries) => {
        console.log(`entry ${entry.id} saved`)
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

const removeEntry = (oldEntry = {}) => {
    let filteredEntries = Entries.filter(entry => entry !== oldEntry)

    journalDB.setItem('entries', filteredEntries).then((entries) => {
        console.log(`entry ${oldEntry.id} removed`)
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

const editEntry = (originEntry = { id }, update = { content }) => {
    let newEntry = { ...originEntry, ...update }
    removeEntry(originEntry)
    addEntry(newEntry)
}

const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route
            path='/'
            element={<RootLayout />}>
            <Route
                id='journal'
                path='journal'
                element={<JournalLayout />}>
                <Route
                    index
                    id='entries'
                    element={<Entries />}
                    loader={async () => { return EntryList }} />
                <Route
                    path='entry/add'
                    action={async ({ params, request }) => {
                        const req = await request.formData()

                        let entry = {
                            id: EntryList.length + 1,
                            content: req.get('content')
                        }

                        addEntry(entry)

                        return EntryList
                    }} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    )
)

createRoot(document.querySelector('#root')).render(
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

**JournalLayout.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Outlet, Form, useFetcher } from 'react-router-dom'

const JournalLayout = () => {
    const fetcher = useFetcher()
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="journal">
                <div>Journal</div>

                <Outlet />

                <div>
                    <fetcher.Form method='put' action='entry/add' >
                        <textarea rows={10} cols={30} type='text' name='content' />
                        <input type="submit" />
                    </fetcher.Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default JournalLayout
```

**Entries.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import style from './Entries.scss'
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom'

const Entries = () => {
    const EntryList = useLoaderData()

    return (
        <div className={style.class}>{EntryList.map(({ id, content }, idx) => <div key={idx}>{id}: {content}</div>)}</div>
    )
}

export default Entries
```

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly, you can use the `useEffect` React hook (to update the content of the `Entries` component

Answer (score 0):

#### Why your problem is happening

After looking over your code a few times, the problem lies in how you initialize the `EntryList` array. You make one call to the database to fetch results and nothing new ever happens to the array. The route also has the `loader` parameter passing back the array and not the results of a *new* call to the database.

Thankfully this is a very easy fix, and it can be done in multiple ways.

---

## First option (off the top of my head)

Instead of passing the `EntryList` array in the route's `loader`, pass the results of a new call to the database (the call should fetch all the entries).

```
<Route
  index
  id="entries"
  element={<Entries />}
  loader={async () => {
    try {
      const newEntries = await journalDB.getItem("entries");
      return newEntries;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // Pass original array when failure occurs.
      return EntryList;
    }
  }}
/>;
```

Problems here is performance. Could be slow, depending on db and how the fetching function is implemented.

---

## Second option (more thought out, less calls to the database, so faster UI)

When adding new entries, make sure you keep the `EntryList` up-to-date. This may be a solution you can use without needing to add some [React Context](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or extra react hook callback code.

If you choose to update the `EntryList` array every time you ADD/DELETE/UPDATE, you need to add the code to all functions that preform crud operations to the database. `addEntry`, `editEntry`, and `removeEntry` need to be updated and tested.

See the code snippet below:

```
let EntryList = (await journalDB.getItem("entries")) || [];

const addEntry = (entry = { id, content }) => {
  journalDB
    .setItem("entries", [...EntryList, entry])
    .then((entries) => {
      // Log to user that it saved
      console.log(`entry ${entry.id} saved`);
      // Rewrite the `EntryList` array with new changes
      EntryList = entries;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

See your full file with the (**some**) changes. I also have prettier format all my files, so I prettified your react code. Sorry!

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";
import localforage from "localforage";

import RootLayout from "./layouts/RootLayout";
import JournalLayout from "./layouts/JournalLayout";
import Entries from "./components/Entries";

const journalDB = localforage.createInstance({
  driver: localforage.INDEXEDDB,
  storeName: "journalDB",
});

// -- Changes I made -----------------------
let EntryList = (await journalDB.getItem("entries")) || [];

const addEntry = (entry = { id, content }) => {
  journalDB
    .setItem("entries", [...EntryList, entry])
    .then((entries) => {
      // Log to user that it saved
      console.log(`entry ${entry.id} saved`);
      EntryList = entries;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
// -----------------------------------------

const removeEntry = (oldEntry = {}) => {
  let filteredEntries = Entries.filter((entry) => entry !== oldEntry);

  journalDB
    .setItem("entries", filteredEntries)
    .then((entries) => {
      console.log(`entry ${oldEntry.id} removed`);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

const editEntry = (originEntry = { id }, update = { content }) => {
  let newEntry = { ...originEntry, ...update };
  removeEntry(originEntry);
  addEntry(newEntry);
};

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route id="journal" path="journal" element={<JournalLayout />}>
        <Route
          index
          id="entries"
          element={<Entries />}
          loader={async () => {
            return EntryList;
          }}
        />
        <Route
          path="entry/add"
          action={async ({ params, request }) => {
            const req = await request.formData();

            let entry = {
              id: EntryList.length + 1,
              content: req.get("content"),
            };

            addEntry(entry);

            return EntryList;
          }}
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);

createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it seems that `EntryList` is computed only once when the app is loaded and the `Routes.jsx` file is processed. The loader function is simply returning the initially computed value.

```js
// Computes entry list when processing file
const EntryList = await journalDB.getItem('entries') || [];

...

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    ...
    <Route
      index
      id='entries'
      element={<Entries />}
      loader={async () => {
        // Returns computed value
        return EntryList;
      }}
    />
    ...
  )
);
```

The loader should call the DB/backend at runtime.

```js
const entryListLoader = async () => {
  // Computes entry list when loader called
  return await journalDB.getItem('entries') || [];
};

...

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    ...
    <Route
      index
      id='entries'
      element={<Entries />}
      loader={entryListLoader}
    />
    ...
  )
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-trigger-loader-function-after-form-is-submitted]